# Didn't find class "zaynaxhealth.com.data.AppApplication" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, android-multidex, jitsi-meet

After updating the jitsi library
from :

```
implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive = true }
```

To :

```
implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:8.2.2') { transitive = true }
```

I got this kind of error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: zaynaxhealth.com, PID: 5036
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application zaynaxhealth.com.util.MyApplication package zaynaxhealth.com: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "zaynaxhealth.com.util.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6746)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "zaynaxhealth.com.util.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~mpqHDLoBytfEohQt-dW0RA==/zaynaxhealth.com-iKeEyzM-15AvUnYKAakL7Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1232)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6746) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5036 SIG: 9
```

I have enabled multidex in my project

I have try several solution from stackoverflow but the problem is not solved yet. Any help would be appreciated.